# Access Rights in ProgramData Windows 10/11

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, active-directory

I'm writing a program that will assist testers in switching directories in ProgramData for the POS company I work for.

In order to accomplish what I'm trying to do I wrote in that a function in my program will be renaming the folder to a version of the type of environment, location, ect:
IE:  TestTesterPOS_prod_NewTown_France

I finished that functionality and am running it under my user which is Domain Admin.

However when I attempt to run another function that will take a directory in a data grid and swap between environments,  it's giving me an Access Error.
I checked and saw that the Admin group has Full access to all folders, sub folders, and files in Program Directory.  However MY Personal user only has access to all of the Folders, NOT subfolders and Files.
The Program in TaskManager is being run under my personal user, NOT admin user or Domain Admin.

I'm getting access Errors when I try to do that second Renaming.   Am I going in the right direction for this or am I looking in the wrong place?

Please note that the Dev Environment is being run as Admin and the UAT is disabled for my test device.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You could of course modify the permissions of the parent folder (e.g. C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\MyProduct) to allow this operation. Or use the user-specific directories %AppData% or %LocalAppData% instead of %ProgramData%.

Comment: That is an option, however the folders to be modified are being written by another program and specifically set so that it's in program data, so I can't put them into Appdata.  

Permissions shouldn't need to be modified, but if they do then that would be difficult since my target audience is not only dev people but also QA who know little about security or permission settings.

Comment: @rzantarra: Run the app as a user that has the appropriate permission to do whatever you are trying to do? Or give the user that the app runs under these permissions.